# How show any class of element with use of media query

Tags: css

Hello everyone i am using media query in my asp.net MVC CSHTML page but it is not working ,It is not showing the element my code is fallowing

```
  @@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
       .MenSection{
       height: 600px;
                width: 460px;

     }
         #menuicon{
           display:table;
       }
     .trMobile{
         display:table;
     }

 #AboutDetails{
    margin-top:8px;
    margin-left:5px;
    padding-left:5px;
      padding-top:1px;

      display:list-item;

}
  #SocialLogin{
      width:auto;
  }
 .AboutDetailsHed{

    font-size:18px;

        margin-left:5px;
        }


    }
```

Here AboutDetailsHed,SocialLogin,AboutDetails is working properly and above three is not working  please help me

Answer (score 0):

It'll be difficult for us to determine how to help you since the syntax is correct. So, here's a simple way to debug your issue.

Since the media query is being added into your context, you need to see why some are not being applied to your elements.

Let's assume you are using Google Chrome browser to debug (emulate a mobile device)

Navigate to your element in the "Elements" pane in dev tools (F12). Go to your element and view the styles for that element. You should see all applied styles. It could be that the style you are setting on the media query is being overwritten by another style.

If that is the case, you need to make sure your media query is added later in your context. Perhaps append `!important` to your style property's value.

Comment: I missed the CSHTML part.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a responsive meta tag to your html document?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```